# How do I write a Spring Boot request filter that is able to retrieve the request controller method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, servlets

I've added this to the component scan path of my Spring Boot application. However, when the request runs, the filter has some attributes, but none are the matching controller HandlerMethod. How do I write a filter that will have access to the controller handler method?

```java
package io.xj.access;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.filter.OrderedFilter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerMapping;

import javax.annotation.security.DenyAll;
import javax.annotation.security.PermitAll;
import javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.util.Objects;

@Component
public class AccessTokenAuthFilter implements OrderedFilter {
  private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(io.xj.hub.access.HubAccessTokenAuthFilter.class);

  // Order defaults to after Spring Session filter
  private final int order = REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER - 10;

  @Override
  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletReq, ServletResponse servletRes, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {
    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletReq;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletRes;

    HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE);

    if (Objects.nonNull(handlerMethod)) {
      Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

      // use reflection to get resource method annotation values
      RolesAllowed aRolesAllowed = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
      PermitAll aPermitAll = method.getAnnotation(PermitAll.class);
      DenyAll aDenyAll = method.getAnnotation(DenyAll.class);

      // todo decide whether we are authenticated
    }

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
  }

  @Override
  public int getOrder() {
    return this.order;
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to retrieve the original request method from the @Controller annotated class that the request came through. Documentation indicates that the following line should work in the body of the method. But it seems to return null when called from my filter:

```java
HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) req.getAttribute(HandlerMapping.BEST_MATCHING_HANDLER_ATTRIBUTE);
```

I placed a breakpoint on the line where I grabbed the handler method.

My debugger shows that the filter chain has four entries and I've ensured that my filter runs last

[image: The filter chain has four entries and I've ensured that my filter runs last]

When my filter is run, there are some attributes, but none about the handler method:

[image: there are some attributes, but none about the handler method]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get the handler method like this:

```
@Component
public class AccessTokenAuthFilter implements OrderedFilter {

    private final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(io.xj.hub.access.HubAccessTokenAuthFilter.class);

    @Autowired
    private org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext appContext;

    // Order defaults to after Spring Session filter
    private final int order = REQUEST_WRAPPER_FILTER_MAX_ORDER - 10;

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletReq, ServletResponse servletRes, FilterChain chain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) servletReq;
        HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) servletRes;

        try {
            RequestMappingHandlerMapping req2HandlerMapping = (RequestMappingHandlerMapping) appContext.getBean("requestMappingHandlerMapping");
            HandlerExecutionChain handlerExeChain = req2HandlerMapping.getHandler(req);
            if (Objects.nonNull(handlerExeChain)) {
                HandlerMethod handlerMethod = (HandlerMethod) handlerExeChain.getHandler();
                Method method = handlerMethod.getMethod();

                // use reflection to get resource method annotation values
                RolesAllowed aRolesAllowed = method.getAnnotation(RolesAllowed.class);
                PermitAll aPermitAll = method.getAnnotation(PermitAll.class);
                DenyAll aDenyAll = method.getAnnotation(DenyAll.class);

                // todo decide whether we are authenticated
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.warn("Cannot get the handler method", e);
        }

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return this.order;
    }
}
```

Be sure there is a `ServletRequestPathFilter` bean registered in the filter chain with a higher order than this filter.

Comment: Unfortunately, in my application, this approach fails again with `Expected parsed RequestPath in request attribute "org.springframework.web.util.ServletRequestPathUtils.PATH".` because the path has not yet been set. In the debugger, I can confirm that the only three attributes available are:
"formContentFilter.FILTERED" -> {Boolean@13601} true
"requestContextFilter.FILTERED" -> {Boolean@13601} true
"characterEncodingFilter.FILTERED" -> {Boolean@13601} true

Comment: Okay, I got your `RequstMappingHandlerMapping` implemention to work! But one critical note, the resolution to the underlying issue. I had to register a `ServletRequestPathFilter` bean in the filter chain with order `Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE` (my app has been refactored from what was previously not a Spring Boot project)

Comment: it will work if you add
 ```ServletRequestPathUtils.parseAndCache(req);```
before
HandlerExecutionChain handlerExeChain = req2HandlerMapping.getHandler(req);